# react-native-document-picker: uri is undefined while used document picker react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

How to fix it:I want to get absolute path but file uei is undefined when used document picker in react native.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker'
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'
import Pdf from 'react-native-open-pdf';


const openPdfex = () => {

 const openFile = () => {
  
    const res =  DocumentPicker.pick({
          type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
        });

        console.log("absolute path =====> " ,res.uri);
  }

 return (
    <View>
      <Text>openPdf</Text>
      <Button title='Open PDF' onPress={openFile}></Button>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, it states that DocumentPicker.pick() returns a promise and because you did not resolve the promise, you are not able to get back the uri from it.

```
  const openFile = async () => {
    try {
      const res = DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
      });

      console.log('absolute path =====> ', res.uri);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Try this and see if it works.

Comment: i try , but still uri is undefined

Comment: I have the same problem and I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it works

```
const openFile = async () => {
try {
  const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
    type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
  });
  console.log('absolute path =====> ', JSON.stringify(res[0]['uri']));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DocumentPicker.pickSingle` instead of `DocumentPicker.pick`